# New Task Sequence Wizard

Tags: tasks, deployment, imaging

How should/do I fill this out?

[image: New Task Sequence Wizard]

I cannot find anything the helps me understand what I should put on this page.  For Example

```
**Full Name** Whose name or Full Name of what
**Organization** I will use ours
**IE Homepage** will be https://www.google.com
```

Can I just leave Full Name as Windows User and will it be blown away after I image it?

I have search and watched all the videos I could but no one goes in depth on this page.  We just started exploring gathering ideas about deploying Windows 7 and knowing this I could move on about my process.

I have a lot done in Microsoft Deployment Toolkit 2012 but not this.

Comment: Not everyone might know that MDT stands for MS Deployment Toolkit. Also, maybe [this](http://labmice.techtarget.com/articles/deploymenttoolkit.htm) will help. (BTW, why not put in the Organization/Company's Name?)

Comment: I am sorry I will make it more clearer for everyone Karan thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 1):

This section of the Task Sequence Wizard applies to the OWNER of the machine. For example if you open Notepad and hit Help>about or Start>Run>winver it will display the info you input ie.

```
Full Name = IT Deparment
Organization= Company Name
IE Home Page= Your Companies website address
```

Thanks to Scriptimus. This guys blog is tremendous and he answers emails very quickly